# Armature is an object?

Tags: rigging, armature

I recently picked up Blender to try and port some models to CSGO and I'm trying to use the armature for the reference model and apply it on the new model that I'll be porting. Problem is, when I delete the mesh of the reference and try to apply the armature I cant find a way to do it. I'm pretty sure that my armature is applied to an object already and through all my googleing i cant find out for the fix it.

here is the .blend (I know the bones and the mesh don't line up yet)
https://puu.sh/sP8cs/2c1c154d05.blend

Comment: You have the mesh as a parent of the armature.  Should be the other way around.

Comment: As I said I'm new to blender, is it easy to fix that?

Comment: Some kind soul may fix your file for you.  I just dragged the armature out of mesh parent in outliner, and then dragged mesh into armature as parent.   Applying an armature deforms a mesh permanently to its current pose, I don't think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Found it ty my dude